Page reloads instead of displaying modal for Edit, Details, and Delete actions
I’m working with an ASP.NET MVC project where I've used Entity Framework to generate CRUD actions for a Student controller. The HomeController handles the main view (Index), which displays a paginated list of students inside a div element. In this Index view, I have three buttons for each student: Edit, Details, and Delete.
When clicking any of these buttons, a modal is supposed to display with the corresponding action's form. However, instead of displaying the modal, the page reloads without showing it. The Index view is expected to load these actions in a modal without navigating away from the HomeController. How can I implement this properly, given that the controller I want the view to redirect to is HomeController
Index.cshtml
Buttons upon clicking the modals should be displayed
@foreach (var item in Model.Student)
{

EDIT



Read



Delete


}
                                                                                         
```
Edit action method:
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)         
{
    if (id == null)             
    {                 
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);             
    } 

    student student = await db.students.FindAsync(id);    

    if (student == null)             
    {                 
        return HttpNotFound();             
    }             

    return View(student);
}  

[HttpPost]         
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]         
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include "studentId,name,surname,birthdate,gender,class,point")] student student)         
{             
    if (ModelState.IsValid)             
    {
        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;                 

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(student);
}  

Javascript to display model
@section Scripts {



<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(url) {
        $('#modalContent').load(url, function () {
            $('#crudModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
</script>

}

Could you provide more code, what is openModal and why are you passing URI to method that is returning a view, if you don't want to redirect?

Sure, openModal is function i created in javascripts that is executed when button is clicked. The modal now displays when I change button type = "button" but returns an empty modal

I suspect that you want to do redirection on click on those buttons? If that's the case then you should add  tag for each action inside modal. Something like this @Model.NameOfBtutton change the href path to your needs if you want to do it in for loop. IF not just hardcode the text between open and close a tags.

Hey @Ammar was that what you've been looking for?

Yes Thanks!!, turns out the only reason it wasn't working was because I never properly referenced the link to the buttons opening the modal
